# Determinant in $\mathbb Z_{5}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need to find

$$ \det\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 4 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 2 & 1
    \end{array}
\right] $$
over $\mathbb Z_{5}$

**What I did:**

$$2\det\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1  & 3 \\
2 & 1
    \end{array}
\right] - 4\det\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1  & 3 \\
3 & 1
    \end{array}
\right]$$

$$=2(1-6) - 4(-8)$$
$$=2(0) - 4(2)$$
$$=2$$

Is this correct? I have never done determinants over a certain set like $\mathbb Z_{5}$ before. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you missing a minus sign in your expansion by minors?

Comment: It appears he accounted for the negative in the next steps though. Other than that the calculation seems fine.

Comment: Agree, it seems to be a typo just on the first line. The answer and method are correct. OP - if you want to double-check your work, you can always compute the determinant over $\mathbb{R}$, which is $22$. Taken modulo $5$, this is equivalent to $2$.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys. Fixed typo too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is the same polynomial in the matrix entries no matter which field (or commutative ring) the entries come from.

So what you're doing is right -- you can think of it either as doing the calculations in $\mathbb Z_5$, or as computing the determinant over $\mathbb Z$ and reducing modulo 5 at the very end.